# Adding a separator to menu in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I am building my first Visual Studio extension, and now that I am nearing the end I am just trying to make it look a little better. I have my own heading in the top menu with items in it. I would like to add a separator to the menu to make it neater, but can't figure out how to do so.

The separator I am talking about is the line that goes across menus/context menus to separate the items.

I am geussing it will have to be added to the xml in the vsct file but incase it's relevant the add-in is in C#.

I can't really find much on this at all, so I am hoping someone can help me out.

**EDIT:I seemed to have figured out my issue. After looking around EVERYWHERE, I got the idea to try putting a couple of the menu items into a different group in the XML vsct file..and VOILA! I now have a cool separator. So the answer is that it is automatically added to separate groups, and it cannot be done by code(or so I think). Remember Extensions don't use C# or VB to add menu items, only add-ins do. Extensions use XML.**

Answer (score 4):

A separator is a visual separation of command groups defined in a .vsct file.

A command group is a logical container for commands belonging together. This kind of grouping also can be used for visual effects.

If you put more than one command group in a menu, a separator is created to visually emphasize the separation of command groups.

To learn more about .vsct files look at: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/03/02/LearnVSXNowPart14.aspx

Comment: Cool. I was looking for this for an hour. It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/f26acf64-0ee6-4947-84e4-a7a0ded9d636

It looks like this is the code, but honestly I have no idea.

```
'Me.AddSeparatorLine(generateCodeCommandBarPopup, 3)   
CType(cmnd_GenerateListDetailFormCode.AddControl(generateCodeCommandBarPopup.CommandBar, 3),CommandBarButton).BeginGroup = True
```

This also looks like it might be useful: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005003.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, that is actually for an add-in which is a little different. It has a specific connection file in C# where I would create menu items/ nsert that, but extensions use XML to create their menu items. Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

In .vcts, `Commands` section is responsible for that functionality. On order to do sthm with menus dynamically you may realise `IVsShellPropertyEvents` interface and do your logic in `OnShellPropertyChange` method

```
public int OnShellPropertyChange(int propid, object propValue)
    {
      // --- We handle the event if zombie state changesfrom true to false
        if ((int)__VSSPROPID.VSSPROPID_Zombie == propid)
        {
            if ((bool)propValue == false)
            {
                // --- Show the commandbar
                EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
                CommandBar cb = ((dte.CommandBars as CommandBars)["YourCommandBar"] as CommandBar);

                foreach (CommandBarControl cbc in cb.Controls)
                {
                    if (cbc.Caption == "YourCaption")
                    {
                        CommandBarButton btn = (CommandBarButton)cbc;
                        btn.BeginGroup = true; // HERE WE ADD NEW GROUP - means add separator
                    }
                }
            }

            // --- Unsubscribe from events

            var shellService = GetService(typeof(SVsShell)) as IVsShell;
            if (shellService != null)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(shellService.UnadviseShellPropertyChanges(_EventSinkCookie));
            }

            _EventSinkCookie = 0;
        }

        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
```

Comment: Okay but how exactly do I add the seperator?

Comment: This is for an extension and not and add-in?

Comment: @user1632018 Looking at your answer, it seems that it works only for add-ins.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure how you're creating the menu, but if you're using the `MenuItem` class, you can pass `"-"` to its constructor to create a separator.

```
MenuItem separator = new MenuItem("-");
```

Comment: Thanks but the menu items are actually created through XML in the VSCT file.